# PHAssetChangeRequest Cocoa error -1

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to save downloaded video to gallery on iPhone, but getting error:

```
The operation couldnt be completed. (Cocoa error -1/)
```

Tried also to do this through `webClient.DownloadDataAsync()`, getting same error. Here is my listing:

```
public async Task<string> DownloadFile(string fileUri)
        {
     var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
            string fileName = fileUri.Split('/').Last();
            var documentsDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string videoFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsDirectory, fileName);
            var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                 var authStatus = await PHPhotoLibrary.RequestAuthorizationAsync();
                if(authStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized){
                    var fetchOptions = new PHFetchOptions();
                    var collections = PHAssetCollection.FetchAssetCollections(PHAssetCollectionType.Album, PHAssetCollectionSubtype.Any, fetchOptions);
                    collection = collections.firstObject as PHAssetCollection;

                    PHPhotoLibrary.SharedPhotoLibrary.PerformChanges(() => {
                        var assetCreationRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.FromVideo(NSUrl.FromFileName(videoFileName));
                        var assetPlaceholder = assetCreationRequest.PlaceholderForCreatedAsset;
                        var albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.ChangeRequest(collection);
                        albumChangeRequest.AddAssets(new PHObject[] { assetPlaceholder });
                    }, delegate (bool status, NSError error) {
                        if (status)
                        {
                            Console.Write("Video added");
                            tcs.SetResult("success");
                        }
                    });

                }
try
            {
                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(fileUri), videoFileName);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                tcs.SetException(e);
            }
            return await tcs.Task;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (Cocoa error -1/)

- Are you sure that you actually have valid data/mp4 from your download?
- Are you using SSL (`https`), otherwise have you applied for an ATS exception in your info.plist?

  - Check the phone/simulator console output for errors concerning ATS

Note: I typically use `NSUrlSession` directly to avoid the `HttpClient` wrapper...

#### Example using `NSUrlSession` task:

```
var videoURL = NSUrl.FromString(urlString);
var videoPath = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User)[0];
NSUrlSession.SharedSession.CreateDownloadTask(videoURL, (location, response, createTaskError) =>
{
    if (location != null && createTaskError == null)
    {
        var destinationURL = videoPath.Append(response?.SuggestedFilename ?? videoURL.LastPathComponent, false);
        // If file exists, it is already downloaded, but for debugging, delete it...
        if (NSFileManager.DefaultManager.FileExists(destinationURL.Path)) NSFileManager.DefaultManager.Remove(destinationURL, out var deleteError);
        NSFileManager.DefaultManager.Move(location, destinationURL, out var moveError);
        if (moveError == null)
        {
            PHPhotoLibrary.RequestAuthorization((status) =>
            {
                if (status.HasFlag(PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized))
                {
                    PHPhotoLibrary.SharedPhotoLibrary.PerformChanges(() =>
                    {
                        PHAssetChangeRequest.FromVideo(destinationURL);
                    }, (complete, requestError) =>
                     {
                        if (!complete && requestError != null)
                            Console.WriteLine(requestError);
                     });
                }
            });
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine(moveError);
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine(createTaskError);
}).Resume();
```

Note: To confirm your code, try using a known valid secure URL source:

https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4 via [“Video For Everybody” Test Page](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html)